# conflicting dependency when trying to install ADT plugin into eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, plugins, dependencies, adt

Here are my specs:
Eclipse: 3.5.2
ADT plugin: 11.0.0
PC: Windows 7

So far, I've installed the Android SDK and Eclipse. However when I attempt to install the ADT plugin into eclipse I get the following error:

> ```
> Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
>   Software being installed: Android Development Tools
> ```
>
> 11.0.0.v201105251008-128486 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.group
>   11.0.0.v201105251008-128486)
>         Software currently installed: Eclipse SDK 3.5.2.M20100211-1343
>   (org.eclipse.sdk.ide
>   3.5.2.M20100211-1343)
>         Only one of the following can be installed at once: 
>           Core Runtime 3.6.0.v20100505 (org.eclipse.core.runtime
>   3.6.0.v20100505)
>           Core Runtime 3.5.0.v20090525 (org.eclipse.core.runtime
>   3.5.0.v20090525)
>         Cannot satisfy dependency:
>           From: Android Development Tools 11.0.0.v201105251008-128486
>   (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.group
>   11.0.0.v201105251008-128486)
>           To: org.eclipse.wst.sse.core 0.0.0
>         Cannot satisfy dependency:
>           From: EMF Common 2.6.0.v20100614-1136 (org.eclipse.emf.common
>   2.6.0.v20100614-1136)
>           To: bundle org.eclipse.core.runtime [3.6.0,4.0.0)
>         Cannot satisfy dependency:
>           From: EMF Common 2.6.0.v20100914-1218 (org.eclipse.emf.common
>   2.6.0.v20100914-1218)
>           To: bundle org.eclipse.core.runtime [3.6.0,4.0.0)
>         Cannot satisfy dependency:
>           From: Eclipse Platform 3.5.2.R35x_v20100210-0800-9hEiFzmFst-TiEn9hNYgDWg1XN8ulH_JvCNGB (org.eclipse.platform.feature.group
>   3.5.2.R35x_v20100210-0800-9hEiFzmFst-TiEn9hNYgDWg1XN8ulH_JvCNGB)
>           To: org.eclipse.rcp.feature.group
>   [3.5.2.R35x_v20100119-9SA0FxwFnoCU5XxWItFdXXb27BA6]
>         Cannot satisfy dependency:
>           From: Eclipse RCP 3.5.2.R35x_v20100119-9SA0FxwFnoCU5XxWItFdXXb27BA6
>   (org.eclipse.rcp.feature.group
>   3.5.2.R35x_v20100119-9SA0FxwFnoCU5XxWItFdXXb27BA6)
>           To: org.eclipse.core.runtime [3.5.0.v20090525]
>         Cannot satisfy dependency:
>           From: Eclipse Project SDK 3.5.2.R35x_v20100119-7Q7bARBPWUHM_CSjz-8bF1f7_n8rLSyWHoiKoyxBQSGT4
>   (org.eclipse.sdk.feature.group
>   3.5.2.R35x_v20100119-7Q7bARBPWUHM_CSjz-8bF1f7_n8rLSyWHoiKoyxBQSGT4)
>           To: org.eclipse.platform.feature.group
>   [3.5.2.R35x_v20100210-0800-9hEiFzmFst-TiEn9hNYgDWg1XN8ulH_JvCNGB]
>         Cannot satisfy dependency:
>           From: Eclipse SDK 3.5.2.M20100211-1343 (org.eclipse.sdk.ide
>   3.5.2.M20100211-1343)
>           To: org.eclipse.sdk.feature.group
>   [3.5.2.R35x_v20100119-7Q7bARBPWUHM_CSjz-8bF1f7_n8rLSyWHoiKoyxBQSGT4]
>         Cannot satisfy dependency:
>           From: Structured Source Model 1.1.500.v201006020308 (org.eclipse.wst.sse.core
>   1.1.500.v201006020308)
>           To: bundle org.eclipse.emf.common [2.4.0,3.0.0)
>         Cannot satisfy dependency:
>           From: Structured Source Model 1.1.502.v201008311901 (org.eclipse.wst.sse.core
>   1.1.502.v201008311901)
>           To: bundle org.eclipse.emf.common [2.4.0,3.0.0)
>         Cannot satisfy dependency:
>           From: Structured Source Model 1.1.504.v201102160550 (org.eclipse.wst.sse.core
>   1.1.504.v201102160550)
>           To: bundle org.eclipse.emf.common [2.4.0,3.0.0)

Any suggestions?
I've seen a few posts about re-installing eclipse, but that's something i'm not comfortable with doing because it was such a pain to find the 64-bit version in the first place.

If you want to suggest re-installing eclipse, i'd greatly appreciate it if you found the download link for the windows 64-bit version. thx :)

or if you know how to fix this error directly that would be really helpful :D

Comment: its only a problem of eclipse not suiting your bit version of your computer...

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the latest ADT version requires Eclipse Helios (3.6).  That seems odd since I can't find where that requirement is documented.

You could try getting a new [Eclipse version](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/epp/downloads/release/helios/SR2/eclipse-java-helios-SR2-win32-x86_64.zip).
You could also grab an earlier ADT version, though I'm having trouble finding that.

Comment: well i did as u said and upgraded eclipse, but now i get THIS error >_<

Comment: An error occurred while installing the items
session context was:(profile=epp.package.java, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Install, operand=null --> [R]org.eclipse.jdt.debug 3.6.1.v20100715_r361, action=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.touchpoint.eclipse.actions.InstallBundleAction).
The artifact file for osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jdt.debug,3.6.1.v20100715_r361 was not found.

Comment: What version of org.eclipse.jdt.debug comes installed with Helios?

Comment: i think that's the version that comes with it

Comment: Damn google and their landmines. Always making simple things hard.

Answer (score 2):

If you are upgrading from 3.6 and you've unizipped the new eclipse in the old original location you will get a confliciting dependency error - only one of these can be installed at a time etc tc.
In that case, delete your old eclipse folder completely. Unzip the new one again there and it will work! No need to add any repositories!

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can uninstall android SDK. Then first add or install adt plugin in eclipse. then on restarting eclipse it's autmatically gonna ask you path for Android SDK. if not asks then just go to Window->prefrences->Android and set the path of the android sdk (unzipped android folder)(path to tools dir).

Comment: nope, i still get the error message after uninstalling android SDK and restarting eclipse.

Comment: hmm have you added or downloaded adt from eclipse update site ?

Answer (score 1):

Probably a bit lat for this but I was running Eclipse Helios 3.6 and got the same type of dependency conflict messages.  I went under the help menu and did a check for updates and it updated the eclipse sdk.  I did a restart and tried installing the ADT plugin again and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse installs default to a workspace called workspace..this causes problems when you attempt to update, etc..as the metadata in the workspace stills has the previous eclipse version stuff in it..

First make a copy of the workspace than delete it and try to install 3.7 and adt again and everything should work..

BTW, from now on...name your eclipse workspace by eclipse version  number to help avoid the problem.