# Eclipse "Conflicting Depencency" errors installing ADT

Tags: android, eclipse

I am setting up Eclipse with ADT. I'm getting the following error:

> Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency. Software being installed:
>   Android Hierarchy Viewer 20.0.3.v201208082019-427395 (com.android.ide.eclipse.hierarchyviewer.feature.group 20.0.3.v201208082019-427395)
>
> Software currently installed:
>   Eclipse IDE for SOA Developers 1.3.0.20100617-0520 (epp.package.soa 1.3.0.20100617-0520)
>
> Only one of the following can be installed at once:
>   Eclipse UI 3.6.1.M20100826-1330 (org.eclipse.ui 3.6.1.M20100826-1330)
>   Eclipse UI 3.6.2.M20110203-1100 (org.eclipse.ui 3.6.2.M20110203-1100)
>   Eclipse UI 3.6.0.I20100603-1100 (org.eclipse.ui 3.6.0.I20100603-1100)

Can anyone tell me how to solve this, or the correct versions of the packages that I need to use to avoid the conflct?

Comment: Did you check for and apply all updates before trying to install ADT?

Comment: There's [a similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6443095/conflicting-dependency-when-trying-to-install-adt-plugin-into-eclipse) with a few ideas too

Answer (score 0):

Ran into this issue trying to install into a working install of Eclipse 4.2.  I went back and downloaded the ADT Bundle from http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html and the install finishes.