# ADT Plugins Update "Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency."

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

```
name=Eclipse Platform
id=org.eclipse.platform
version=4.3.0
```

my eclipse version is 4.3.0.......give me a help

Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6443095/conflicting-dependency-when-trying-to-install-adt-plugin-into-eclipse

Comment: thank y,my version is 4.3.0,but i also have the same problem...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Download bundles from here:

linux 64 bit vm: http://dl.google.com/android/adt/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20140702.zip

linux 32 bit vm: http://dl.google.com/android/adt/adt-bundle-linux-x86-20140702.zip

mac: http://dl.google.com/android/adt/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140702.zip

win32: http://dl.google.com/android/adt/adt-bundle-windows-x86-20140702.zip

win64: http://dl.google.com/android/adt/adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702.zip

Starting with ADT bundle 23.0.2, you should be able to update to future versions of ADT.

Source: official android google groups

Comment: thank y,i download the eclipse from eclipse.com.and add the ADT zip to it.my bundles download from android developer can not remove adt plugin .